# Is RoutePrefix attribute substring sensitive?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have created three WebAPI controllers decorated with `RoutePrefix` attribute. There's a shared part of the route as shown below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users")
public class ControllerOne : ApiController
{
   ...
}

[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users/books")
public class ControllerTwo : ApiController
{
   ...
}

[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users/movies")
public class ControllerThree : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("")]
   public void Foo(){}
}
```

When I call Foo method (using address `.../api/foo/users/movies/`) I get the following exception:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL. The request has found the following matching controller types:
>   ...exception.

Is `RoutePrefix` attribute substring sensitive?

Comment: Why are you using same controller name mulitple time?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Pardon me, there are three controllers I made mistake here on SO.

Comment: You must be careful with routes and parameters. For example, if your route `api/foo/users` expects a string as a parameter, both  `api/foo/users`,  `api/foo/users/movies` and `api/foo/users/books` will be a valid call to `api/foo/users/parameter`, and web api will not know to what route he will send your request

Comment: Can you add the actions for each controller? I think that some action in ControllerOne match some actions in other controllers.

Comment: An action in `ControllerOne` matches a "movies" route.

Comment: Wow I can't believe they broke attribute routing when they made it a first class citizen.

Comment: Somewhere in the other controllers you are using a general route that matches `api/foo/users/movies`. Most probably in `ControllerOne`. Show the actions/routes for `ControllerOne`

Comment: @RafaelMarques Thank you Rafael, your hint helped me to understand the issue. It's surprising to me though that even integer variables in the address will cause problems (see my answer). Not completely surprising because I guess type is recognized later, but still a bit surprising...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `web api` what is the type of your parameter. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users")]
public class FirstControllerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "users ;)";
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users/movies")]
public class SecondControllerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get()
    {
        return "movies ;)";
    }
}
```

Using `[Route("{id:int}")]`, that route will be valid only if you send an integer. If it is not, it will be available as a "free route". That way, if you do:

`GET /api/foo/users/10`

You'll get the response `"users ;)"`

And if you do:

`GET /api/foo/users/movies`

You'll get the response `"movies ;)"`

I think using the `{id:int}` will help with your problem! But always be careful when you are creating your routes! ;)

Answer (score 0):

`RoutePrefix` is not substring sensitive - however any post-fix variable in the address - **even if it's integer** - will cause mentioned exception.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users")
public class ControllerOne : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{someVariable}")]
   public string Bar(int someVariable){return "FooBar";}
}

[RoutePrefix("api/foo/users/movies")
public class ControllerThree : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("")]
   public void Foo(){}
}
```

In the code above `Bar` method will interfere with `RoutePrefix` of `ControllerThree`.

Comment: You can restrict the type of your parameter, I'll write an answer showing that! ;)